# Need to find the full team under a manager

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to write a SP to find the full team under manager X. Full team in the sense, I would like to find all the direct and indirect reportees under a manager X. I am using SQL Server 2005.

The Employee table Structure is:

```
EmployeeNumber  FirstName  LastName  ManagerEmployeeNumber
```

For example, if SP has the input as Employee Number = 10211, then the output should be like this:

```
EmployeeNumber  FirstName  LastName  ManagerEmployeeNumber
13903           Anil       S         10211
1260            David      D         13903
8079            Donald     K         1260
```

I have written the needed things to find the full team under manager X in a function as:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FullTeamUnderManager1](@ManagerId int)  
RETURNS   
@EmployeeList TABLE   
( 
 EmployeeName Varchar(200) 
)  
AS  
BEGIN  

 With hierarchy(EmployeeName, Employee_Id, SupEmp_Id, Depth) as  
 (  
  Select (first_name + ', ' + last_name) EmployeeName, employee_number, employee_number as supemp_id, 0 as depth  
     From dbo.employee  
     Where employee_number = @ManagerId  
  union all   
  Select (child.first_name + ', ' + child.last_name), child.employee_number, child.manager_employee_number, parent.depth + 1   
  From dbo.employee As child  
  Inner Join hierarchy As parent  
      On child.manager_employee_number = parent.Employee_Id  
     Where child.employee_number != parent.Employee_Id  

 )  
 insert into @EmployeeList(EmployeeName)  
  select EmployeeName from hierarchy where depth > 0  
  order by EmployeeName
 RETURN   
END
```

I need to combine it with the below SP. The output should be a single column as 'EmployeeName'

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetCorpDirDistributionTableUsers]            
@activeOnly bit = 1,            
@employeesOnly bit = 1,            
@isAllowedNonEmployees bit = 0,      
@isAllowedNonEmployeesInOrgChart bit = 0, 
@login_employee_number INT = NULL,      
@IsGetLocations bit = 0,
@Location_IDLIST VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@IsGetDepartments bit = 0,
@Department_IDLIST VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@IsGetDirectReports bit = 0,
@IsGetDirectReportsManagers bit = 0,
@IsGetAllManagers bit=0,
@manager_employee_number INT

   AS    
   DECLARE @employeeTypeId int       

   SET @employeeTypeId = 1           
   SET @isAllowedNonEmployees = ISNULL(@isAllowedNonEmployees, 0) 
   SET @isAllowedNonEmployeesInOrgChart  = ISNULL(@isAllowedNonEmployeesInOrgChart, 0)               
   SET @IsGetDirectReports = ISNULL(@IsGetDirectReports, 0) 
   SET @IsGetDirectReportsManagers  = ISNULL(@IsGetDirectReportsManagers, 0)

   SELECT         
    (e1.first_name + ', ' + e1.last_name) EmployeeName,
   FROM EMPLOYEE e1           
   LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE e2 on e1.manager_employee_number = e2.employee_number             
   INNER JOIN LOCATION loc ON e1.location_id = loc.location_id   
   INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT dep ON e1.department_id = dep.department_id                  
   LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE_TYPE emptype ON e1.employee_type_id = emptype.employee_type_id            
   WHERE          
     e1.visible = 1 and             
     (@activeOnly = 0 OR @activeOnly IS NULL OR e1.active_flag = 1) and            
     (@isAllowedNonEmployees = 1 or e1.employee_type_id = @employeeTypeId) and             
     (@employeesOnly = 0 or e1.employee_type_id = @employeeTypeId) and  



  --Location
  (@IsGetLocations=0 OR
  (COALESCE(@Location_IDLIST,'%') = '%' OR e1.location_id IN (SELECT Segment FROM dbo.fn_GetParsedValues(@Location_IDLIST,',')))) and

  --Department
  (@IsGetDepartments=0 OR
  (COALESCE(@Department_IDLIST,'%') = '%' OR e1.Department_ID IN (SELECT Segment FROM dbo.fn_GetParsedValues(@Department_IDLIST,',')))) and      

  --IsGetDirectReports
  (@IsGetDirectReports=0 OR
    ((e1.manager_employee_number = @manager_employee_number and e1.active_flag = 1 and e1.visible = 1)    
      and ((@isAllowedNonEmployees = 1 and  @isAllowedNonEmployeesInOrgChart = 1) or e1.employee_type_id = @employeeTypeId))) and

  --IsGetDirectReportsManagers
  (@IsGetDirectReportsManagers=0 OR
  ((e1.manager_employee_number = @manager_employee_number and e1.active_flag = 1 and e1.visible = 1)    
      and ((@isAllowedNonEmployees = 1 and  @isAllowedNonEmployeesInOrgChart = 1) or e1.employee_type_id = @employeeTypeId)
      and (select count(*) from employee e3 where manager_employee_number = e1.employee_number and active_flag = 1 and ((@isAllowedNonEmployees = 1 and  @isAllowedNonEmployeesInOrgChart = 1) or e3.employee_type_id = @employeeTypeId))>0
    )) and

  --IsGetAllManagers
  (@IsGetAllManagers=0 OR
  ((SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.employee e2 WHERE e2.manager_employee_number = e1.employee_number ) > 0) AND
    @IsGetDirectReports=0 AND @IsGetDirectReportsManagers=0)

order by EmployeeName
```

Anybody please helpout... Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091050/how-to-use-cte-to-map-parent-child-relationship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
      EmployeeNumber, FirstNAme, LastName, ManagerEmployeeNumber 
    FROM Emps
    WHERE EmployeeNumber = @EmpNumberToFind
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.*
    FROM CTE c
    INNER JOIN Emps t ON c.EmployeeNumber = t.ManagerEmployeeNumber
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc943/1)

For instance, for the `EmployeeNumber  = 13903`, this will give you:

```
| EMPLOYEENUMBER | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | MANAGEREMPLOYEENUMBER |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|          13903 |      Anil |        S |                 10211 |
|           1260 |     David |        D |                 13903 |
|           8079 |    Donald |        K |                  1260 |
```

Comment: I have used it already and got the output. But I need to combine it with another SP which is not possible. So that I am searching any other way to solve this by writing simple SP...

Comment: I didn't getting what is not possible combine with other SP?

Comment: @prabuR Can you please edit your question, explaining this issue with the query you tried. Thanks.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : I have edited the ques...Kindly have a look and please help out...Thanks

Comment: @prabuR Try to break your code inside that procedure into small queries, then ensure that each part works correctly. But I couldn't understand that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to accomplish this

Comment: I have used it already and got the output. But I need to combine it with another SP which is not possible. So that I am searching any other way to solve this by writing simple queries...