# knockout - bind tree structure based on parent id pointing to the primary key column

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, t-sql, knockout.js

I am trying to bind data returned from a stored procedure in a tree structure by the following [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) knockout documentation.

I am getting data from stored procedure in the following format:

```
ID  | Name                     | ParentID
1   | Parent 1                 | 0
2   | Parent 2                 | 0
3   | Parent 1 Child 1         | 1
4   | Parent 2 Child 1         | 2
5   | Parent 1 Child 1 Child   | 3
6   | Parent 2 Child 1 Child 1 | 4
7   | Parent 2 Child 1 Child 2 | 4
```

In the `ParentID` column, 0 indicates root items and all the other items are pointing to the `ID` column in a parent child relationship. There can be `N` levels of parent child relationships and I have a requirement to bind them in a tree structure like:

```
Parent 1
  Parent 1 Child 1
    Parent 1 Child 1 Child

Parent 2
  Parent 2 Child 1
    Parent 2 Child 1 Child 1
    Parent 2 Child 1 Child 2
```

In the documentation, it shows binding the child items on `click` event but I need to bind all the items at once and this is the part where I am getting confused. Is there any other way to bind tree structure using knockout based on the stored procedure result given above?

Comment: I don't know about the knockout.js but you can use recursive CTE to get the result within your proc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091050/how-to-use-cte-to-map-parent-child-relationship

Comment: @sqluser i already have the query to get the data in the format posted in your question, I need to use to this data to bind data in html using knockoutJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create `computed` to represent only root items from source array and one helper-function to get child items for the current item:

```
var treeData = [
    { id: 1, name: "Parent 1", parent_id: 0 },
    { id: 2, name: "Parent 2", parent_id: 0 },
    { id: 3, name: "Parent 1 Child 1", parent_id: 1 },
    { id: 4, name: "Parent 2 Child 1", parent_id: 2 },
    { id: 5, name: "Parent 1 Child 1 Child", parent_id: 3 },
    { id: 6, name: "Parent 2 Child 1 Child 1", parent_id: 4 },
    { id: 7, name: "Parent 2 Child 1 Child 2", parent_id: 4 }
];

function ViewModel(data) {

    this.allItems = ko.observableArray(data);

    this.rootItems = ko.computed(function(){
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.allItems(), function(item){
            return item.parent_id == 0;
        });
    }, this);

    this.children = function(parent){
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.allItems(), function(item){
            return parent.id == item.parent_id;
        });
    };

}
```

Then you can output the nested list of any depth using named template like:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'list-item', foreach: rootItems }"></ul>

<script type="text/html" id="list-item">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'list-item', foreach: $root.children($data) }"></ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

The result: http://jsfiddle.net/jwquemL6/

P.S. It's very simplified working example so you may want to wrap all items into specific data structure and to prevent every `<li>` node to have `<ul>` (even empty).

Hope you understand the approach.